.NET 8 Windows Service with MSIX Package
I'm trying to make a Windows service in .NET 8 to go along with a WinUI3 desktop application. The service program works fine when debugging in Visual Studio, but I'm running into issues packaging it. I'm trying to follow the instructions here: .NET Core Service Guide and MSIX Service Guide, but I'm not able to get the package to successfully build.
The MSIX instructions say to add a <desktop6:Service> element to the Package.appxmanifest file, which I have done. The documentation says that the Executable and EntryPoint Attributes in the parent desktop6:Extension are optional, but I get an error when building the package without them. If I try to specify them, I get this error: Manifest validation error: Line 33, Column 136, Reason: The file name "BootManagerService.exe" declared for element "*[local-name()='Applications']/*[local-name()='Application']/*[local-name()='Extensions']/*[local-name()='Extension' and not(@Category='windows.backgroundTasks' or @Category='windows.appService')]" doesn't exist in the package.
Here is the relevant section of my Package.appxmanifest:
      <Extensions>
        <desktop6:Extension
          xmlns:desktop6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10/6"
          Category="windows.service"
          Executable="BootManagerService.exe"
          EntryPoint="BootManager.Service.Program">
          <desktop6:Service
            Name="BootManager Service"
            StartupType="auto"
            StartAccount="localSystem">
          </desktop6:Service>
        </desktop6:Extension>
      </Extensions>

I'm not sure if I'm using the desktop6:Service element correctly or if I have another issue. Anyone have any suggestions?
